# mongoDB and rails - privileges and roles needed for a web user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I'm setting up user authentication on mongoDB and would like my rails app to still be able to communicate to the DB. 
I have the configurations set properly as far as I know, but get the error `Not authorized on <db> to excecute command { distinct: "<collection>", key: "<field_name>", query: {} }` 
Currently I am using 'webUser' with `readWrite` privileges.

What mongoDB privilege do I need to grant the web user to run this query? 
Btw, I do have `auth_source, username, password, roles` declared properly in `mongoid.yml`

Thanks in advance!

**Update** - screenshot of db users:
[image: Screenshot of db users]

Comment: Please log in as a privileged user and add the output of `db.getUsers()` in the database defined as auth_source to your question by using the edit button.

Comment: just added a screenshot to the post!